# Facebook permissions and null data handling

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I have to issues I have come across with regards to Facebook Login -

**1st being -**

[image]

[image]

Above are 2 images of a users Facebook app settings (Facebook>>settings>>apps>>{select an app})

As seen in the Asphalt app next to each permission is a (required) tag. But incase of my app there is no (required) tag next to the email permission even though I'am explicitly asking for these perms in the javascript sdk during FB.login(). Any idea how I can get these perms to be required by default or what am I missing ??

**2nd being -**

In another case (very) few users seem to have granted all perms (that is accepted the fb app in the fb dialog box) but for some reason their public_info and/or email seems to be unchecked in the respective user settings under the app dialog/modal as in the above image. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a permission as required from the App Details tab > Configure App Center Permissions

Read more about this [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/appcenter/tutorial#authorization).

As for your second question, could it be the users in question revoked the permissions themselves? even-though *Public profile* is always required so there might be a bug and hence you can report it here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: You are right about the first part. As for the not getting the email, well it seems facebook does not pass/return the email if the user did not verify his/her email during signup.

Comment: @ShalomSam, you are correct. There are some cases where an email won't be returned. [See this for more info](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/298946933534016).